# Payflow in magento 1610 is creating reference charges... why?

Tags: magento, paypal, payflowlink

I am setting up PayFlowLink in Magento. It requires an Authorization transaction when the customer enters his/her Credit Card information. If the customer then clicks the infamous "place order" button the PayFlow module then charges the card as a Reference transaction to the initial Authorization (should use a new trans ID) instead of actually completing the initial Auth as a Sale transaction (same trans ID).

Since Reference Transactions are by default not allowed in the payflow setup, I get a "Failed Merchant Rule Check" back from Paypal.

But... if I turn on "Allow reference transactions" in the manager.paypal.com security settings, Magento sends the same transaction ID to PayPal and PayPal is expecting a new transaction ID for the reference charge. Thus, I get, "The transaction was refused as a result of a duplicate invoice ID supplied"

So... it seems to me that the Magento PayFlowLink module is trying to complete the earlier Auth transaction with a Sale, using the same ID (which is typical across all payment modules)... but that PayPal is for some reason thinking the charge as a reference charge. I hope that the PayFlow module is not that badly written, so its either configuration or some other interference from a template, etc...

Any experience from the cloud is welcome. Thanks!

Edit to add:

I cannot see how paypal can see this as a ref transaction:

```
2012-01-25T18:52:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
[request] => Array
    (
        [user] => ****
        [vendor] => p***
        [partner] => PayPal
        [pwd] => ****
        [verbosity] => HIGH
        [tender] => C
        [amt] => 7.27
        [currency] => USD
        [trxtype] => S
        [origid] => EDN*********
    )

[result] => Array
    (
        [result] => 117
        [pnref] => EWV*********
        [respmsg] => Failed merchant rule check
        [transtime] => 2012-01-25 10:52:39
        [amt] => 7.27
        [cardtype] => 
        [result_code] => 117
    )

[__pid] => 1****
```

)

Comment: And what did Magento say when you mentioned this possible bug to them?
By the way, "Failed merchant rule check" means that the transaction didn't pass the Fraud Protection Services filter(s) you have set up on your account; it doesn't mean you're not allowed to use Reference Transactions, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Magento vis bug report... heh. I have not filed it as a bug report yet, still collecting data. I would assume there would already be chatter if it were a module bug. Re Fraud Protection Filters: yes, "allowing ref transactions" is one of the Fraud Filter options.

Comment: yeah... I think it is a bug. I submitted the full report here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=13012